Get slug to update when attribute of association changes
I have Attraction and Venue models.  Their associations are:
Attraction
belongs_to :venue

Venue
has_many :attractions, dependent: :nullify

I'm using the friendly_id gem to add slugs to both. They are added with:
Attraction
friendly_id :slugged_name_and_venue, use: :slugged

Venue
friendly_id :slugged_name_and_location, use: :slugged

The problem I have is that, because the Attraction slug contains the name and location_1 attributes of the venue association, if the name or location_1 attributes get changed, then the slug of the Attraction is incorrect. I need them to be updated to always stay in sync.

I know the concept of slugs is to keep one unique consistent string that never changes.  I understand this, but this is not how i need this to work.

I know that including values from associations in a slug is also a bad idea, but in this case I need this. I don't typically do this.


I've tried a varying number of options, but none of them actually successfully get the associated Attraction slugs to update.
My latest attempt is this:
Venue
  def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
    slug.blank? || name_changed? || location_1_changed?
    end

    after_update :update_attraction_slugs, if: :should_update_attraction_slugs?

  private

  def should_update_attraction_slugs?
    saved_change_to_name? || saved_change_to_location_1?
  end

  def update_attraction_slugs
    attractions.find_each(&:save)
  end

Attraction
    def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
        slug.blank? || slug_changed? || name_changed? || full_name_changed? || venue_id_changed? || venue_name_or_location_1_changed?
    end

  def venue_name_or_location_1_changed?
    saved_change_to_attribute?(:venue_id) || venue.saved_change_to_name? || venue.saved_change_to_location_1?
  end

Is anyone able to help me out here?

I don't get how you think this should work. "The problem I have is that, because the Attraction slug contains the name and location_1 attributes of the venue association". Slugs must be unique but you have a one-to-many association. When getting an attraction with Venue.freindly.find("foo-bar") which one would you get? The first? The last? All of them?

they will be unique.  the slug of an attraction is the attractions name, the attractions venue name, and the attractions venue location_1.    the Venues slug is the venues name and Location_1. eg: magic-boat-ride-castle-park-perth, and for the venue: castle-park-perth.

for the app im creating, this is how i wish it to work.  please can you help me resolve the issue rather than pointing out the business logic of my app?  i understand that its relevant but different apps have different business logic and what ive already posted os correct for mine.

Just make sure your methods return true when needed.
class Venue < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :attractions, dependent: :destroy

  after_update :update_attraction_slugs, if: :should_update_attraction_slugs?

  def should_update_attraction_slugs?
    saved_change_to_name? || saved_change_to_location_1?
  end

  def update_attraction_slugs
    attractions.find_each(&:save)
  end
end

class Attraction < ApplicationRecord
  extend FriendlyId

  belongs_to :venue

  friendly_id :slugged_name_and_venue, use: :slugged

  def slugged_name_and_venue
    "#{venue.name} #{venue.location_1}"
  end

  # `saved_change_to_attribute?(:venue_id)` doesn't work on creation
  def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
    venue_id_changed? || venue.saved_change_to_name? || venue.saved_change_to_location_1?
  end
end

>> Venue.create!(name: "ven1", location_1: "loc1")
=> #<Venue:0x00007fd62fbaf650 id: 6, name: "ven1", location_1: "loc1">

>> Venue.first.attractions.create!
=> #<Attraction:0x00007fd62fd15bc0 id: 1, venue_id: 6, slug: "ven1-loc1">
#                                                             ^^^^^^^^^

>> Venue.first.update!(name: "ven2")
  Venue Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "venues".* FROM "venues" ORDER BY "venues"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  Venue Update (0.4ms)  UPDATE "venues" SET "name" = ? WHERE "venues"."id" = ?  [["name", "ven2"], ["id", 6]]
  Attraction Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "attractions".* FROM "attractions" WHERE "attractions"."venue_id" = ? ORDER BY "attractions"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["venue_id", 6], ["LIMIT", 1000]]
  Attraction Exists? (0.1ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "attractions" WHERE "attractions"."id" != 1 AND "attractions"."slug" = ? LIMIT ?  [["slug", "ven2-loc1"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Attraction Exists? (0.1ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "attractions" WHERE "attractions"."id" != 1 AND "attractions"."slug" = ? LIMIT ?  [["slug", "ven2-loc1"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Attraction Update (0.1ms)  UPDATE "attractions" SET "slug" = ? WHERE "attractions"."id" = ?  [["slug", "ven2-loc1"], ["id", 1]]
  TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  commit transaction
=> true

>> Venue.first.attractions
=> [#<Attraction:0x00007fd62fba7810 id: 1, venue_id: 6, slug: "ven2-loc1">]
#                                                              ^^^^^^^^^


Hey @alex  Thanks for the answer.  I think the issue is somewhere in here:
`def venue_name_or_location_1_changed?
Rails.logger.info("======== HERE 2 ============")
Rails.logger.info(saved_change_to_attribute?(:venue_id))
Rails.logger.info(venue.saved_change_to_name?)
Rails.logger.info(venue.saved_change_to_location_1?)
saved_change_to_attribute?(:venue_id) || venue.saved_change_to_name? || venue.saved_change_to_location_1?

end`
I get false output for all three.  What could be causing that?

@rctneil all of these methods only work when updating, if you're creating a new record all of them are false. using venue_id_changed? instead seem to work.
